# Thinking in java library installation

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

Hi i've been trying to install the library on  Thinking in Java book  4th edition and i hit a very thick brick wall. I've done everything that the guide from the website told me to do and i still can't get the library to work. From what i've read it seems that the problem is from the build.xml files. having no xml knowledge I am clueless about how I have to modify it in order for it to work. In both cmd and eclipse I am getting these error

c:\TIJ4\code\build.xml

Build Failed

c:\TIJ4\code\build.xml:59:J2SE5 required

Can anyone tell me what I should do ?

I am using eclipse if there is a simpler solution by using eclipse rather than ant please help me out. It's been a week now and I still can't make it work.

Comment: Well, you should post the chunk of the Ant script that's actually causing the error. Right now it sounds like there's either (a) a dependency on SE5, which you don't have, or (b) an artificial dependency on SE5 and you have a version > 5, and haven't compensated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing to do is to realize that your ant file has a specific java requirement.

Something to try that might fix this very easily : I believe you can remove any references to a specific JDK, and if you have a reasonably up to date JDK, the build will succeed.

The definete fix : Look into the exact (line 59) of your build file, and try to satisfy the java version that line requires.  Java is generally backwords compatible -- something designed to run in J2SE5 should run in the latest JDK.  Its not terribly difficult to update your JDK (just google for instructions on your OS).

- The most common mistake I see is that people who have the java run time installed believe they also have the Java SDK as well.

Answer (score 0):

Does this "install the library" means you want to look at the code and run them in your eclipse? If so I can share my experience with you.

1. First run the `Eclipse.py` script; this will add package info to the source code
2. Create a new Java project in Eclipse, and then just copy all the source code folders to the `src` source folder in eclipse, these folders will then be recognized as Java packages.
3. You should be able to run the classes with a `main` function.

You can also configure which java version to use for this project in Eclipse build path. 1.5 or higher will work.